# Using routerlink and router-outlet in different components

Tags: java, angular

I have two components A and B. Now i am using both these in another component C. Now what i want to do is I have the routerLink setup in component A and have setup router-outlet setup in B. So I want to have a couple of links in component A clicking which will change the component to be loaded in B.
I tried this but its not working that way. But when i put both the routerLink and router-outlet in B only it works.
Any code example to do it ??

Component A :

```html
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" class="side-nav-container">
  <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
    <div style="width: 80%; border-bottom: 1px solid #696464" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
      <img style="border-radius: 50%" src="../../../assets/images/MyImage.jpg" class="logo">
      <p>Welcome</p>
      <h3>{{userName}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="button-div" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
      <button mat-button [ngClass]="{'inactive' : homeToggle, 'active': !homeToggle}" (click)="homeHighlightToggle()">
        <em class="fa fa-home font"></em>
        <span class="font-style">Home<a routerLink="/userHome"></a></span>
      </button>
      <button mat-button [ngClass]="{'inactive' : profileToggle, 'active': !profileToggle}" (click)="profileHighlightToggle()">
        <em class="fa fa-user font"></em>
        <span class="font-style">User Profile</span>
      </button>
      <button mat-button [ngClass]="{'inactive' : notificationToggle, 'active': !notificationToggle, 'inactive-notification' : (notificationToggle && notification)}" (click)="notificationHighlightToggle()">
        <em class="fa fa-bell font"></em>
        <span class="font-style">{{notificationsTitle}}<a routerLink="/userNotifications"></a></span>
      </button>
      <button mat-button [ngClass]="{'inactive' : historyToggle, 'active': !historyToggle}" (click)="historyHighlightToggle()">
        <em class="fa fa-history font"></em>
        <span class="font-style">Case History</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 300px; padding-bottom: 15px" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="end center" >
    <button mat-button class="inactive">
      <em class="fa fa-power-off font"></em>
      <span class="font-style"> Logout</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component B:

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center stretch">
  <app-side-nav></app-side-nav>
  <a routerLink="/userHome">Home</a>
  <a routerLink="/userNotifications">Notifications</a>
  <div class="main-body">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the app-routing.module.ts :

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {UserHomeMainBodyComponent} from './components/user-home-main-body/user-home-main-body.component';
import {UserNotificationsBodyComponent} from './components/user-notifications-body/user-notifications-body.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'userHome', component: UserHomeMainBodyComponent},
  {path: 'userNotifications', component: UserNotificationsBodyComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: You have the use case where you have nested router-outlet, so you have to use children routes.

Here you have some documentation : https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes

Comment: Agreed with @RzvRazvan you should read up on child routes, as its not a good approach to use router outlet in multiple components

Comment: Can you please provide and stackblitz url  ?, it can be solve by using children routes.

Comment: I think i might have made some wrong explanation here. So to keep it simple - I need to have the navigation links (routerLinks) in one component and the router-outlet in another ?? Can someone tell how it can be done ??